# Why 'eval' execution gives error?

Tags: javascript, eval

I have following code in HTML part:

```
<script>
    var trainings = {'M':new PlayerTraining(18369,22,355),'D':new PlayerTraining(9412,6,118)};
</script>
```

This code works well, and 'PlayerTraining' is class defined in one of js-files referenced above.

But when I execute:

```
<script>
    alert(eval("{'M':new PlayerTraining(18369,22,355),'D':new PlayerTraining(9412,6,118)}"));
</script>
```

I receive the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

What am I doing wrong? In the end I need to assign that hash (received from WebService) to variable. How to do that?

Please advise.

Comment: `eval("{'M':new PlayerTraining(18369,22,355),'D':new PlayerTraining(9412,6,118)}")` is (more or less) the same as `<script>{'M':new PlayerTraining(18369,22,355),'D':new PlayerTraining(9412,6,118)}</script>` -> SyntaxError

Comment: The `{` is seen as the start of a block. The following up to the closing `}` is expected to be a sequence of statements. 'M' is a string literal and `:` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you should wrap your expression in the parentheses:

```
alert(eval("({'M':new PlayerTraining(18369,22,355),'D':new PlayerTraining(9412,6,118)})"));
```

and to assign the result to a variable do it like this:

```
var someVar = eval("(" + webServiceResponse + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't eval objects like that.

Similar to your example, this will throw a syntax error:

```
{ a: new Date(), b: new Date() }
```

This is because you're missing a variable assignment:

```
var x = { a: new Date(), b: new Date() }
```

You shouldn't be using `eval` in the first place, though. [It's unsafe, and inefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

Comment: I received JSON data from web service, so I consider that as efficient. Is that safe? Dunno, hope yes. See no concerns so far.

Comment: Oh, save would be to parse string... got it. Agree, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside `eval` assign your object to a var:

```
eval("var myVar = {'M':new PlayerTraining(18369,22,355),'D':new PlayerTraining(9412,6,118)};");
alert(myVar);
```

<strike>But anyway, If you have the object as string, you can parse as json.</strike>

Comment: `JSON.parse` only accepts valid JSON. Those functions calls aren't valid JSON.

Comment: @Cerbrus correct. Sorry